# Python/Kivy - How to add a drop down item when a button is pressed: AttributeError 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I developed a simple UI in Kivy/KivyMD - Python. When a button is pressed a dropdown item should be visualized https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.1/components/dropdownitem/. Whilst the majority of examples consider a dropdown item already designed in the UI, I need to add it in the Py code, specifically in the *on-release* event associated to the button.

Here is my code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivymd.uix.dropdownitem.dropdownitem import MDDropDownItem



Builder.load_string(
    """    
<View>:
    MDGridLayout:
        rows: 3
        id: layout
        padding: 100, 50, 100, 50
        
        
        MDRaisedButton:
            id: button
            text: 'CREATE DDI'
            on_release: root.Button_On_Click()
        

""")



class View(MDScreen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(View, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
        
    def Button_On_Click(self):        
        myDdi = MDDropDownItem(
            # size_hint_x = None,
            # width = dp(100),
            # pos_hint = {"right": 1, "center_y": 0.5},
            text = 'SELECT POSITION')
        
        myMenu, scratch = Create_DropDown_Widget(myDdi, ['POS 1', 'POS 2', 'POS 3'], width=4)
        myDdi.on_release = myMenu.open()
        
        self.ids.layout.add_widget(myDdi)
        
       
    def Create_DropDown_Widget(self, drop_down_item, item_list, width):
        items_collection = [
            {
                "viewclass": "OneLineListItem",
                "text": item_list[i],
                "height": dp(56),
                "on_release": lambda x = item_list[i]: self.Set_DropDown_Item(drop_down_item, menu, x),
            } for i in range(len(item_list))
        ]
        
        menu = MDDropdownMenu(caller=drop_down_item, items=items_collection, width_mult=width)
        menu.bind()
        
        return menu, items_collection

         
    def Set_DropDown_Item(self, drop_down_item, menu, text_item):
        drop_down_item.set_item(text_item)
        menu.dismiss()
        
        
        

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.View = View()


    def build(self):
        self.title = ' DROP DOWN ITEM ADDED DYNAMICALLY'
        return self.View


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Trying to execute the code, when I press the button I get this error:

```
line 49, in Button_On_Click
     text = 'SELECT POSITION')

File "C:\Users\\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\behaviors\declarative_behavior.py", line 311, in __init__
     super().__init__(**kwargs)

File "C:\Users\\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\kivymd\theming.py", line 1668, in __init__
     super().__init__(**kwargs)

File "C:\Users\\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 121, in __init__
     super(ButtonBehavior, self).__init__(**kwargs)

File "C:\Users\\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\boxlayout.py", line 145, in __init__
     super(BoxLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

File "C:\Users\\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\layout.py", line 76, in __init__
     super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

File "C:\Users\\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 357, in __init__
     super(Widget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 262, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.__init__
File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 520, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 567, in kivy.properties.Property.set
File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 606, in kivy.properties.Property._dispatch
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1307, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1213, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
File "C:\Users\\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\dropdownitem\dropdownitem.py", line 96, in on_text
     self.ids.label_item.text = text_item

File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 964, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 **AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `KivyMD` is not designed for use in `declarative` style, it is intended to be used in `kv` language. From the [documentation](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/behaviors/declarative/#:%7E:text=The%20KivyMD%20library%20does%20not%20support%20creating%20Kivy,from%20the%20Kivy%20widget%20and%20the%20DeclarativeBehavior%20class%3A):

> The KivyMD library does not support creating Kivy widgets in Python
> code in a declarative style.

The documentation goes on to say:

> But you can still use the declarative style of creating Kivy widgets
> in Python code. To do this, you need to create a new class that will
> be inherited from the Kivy widget and the DeclarativeBehavior class

However, this will not work with the `MDDropDownItem`. One way around this issue is to create the `MDDropDowmItem` instance without providing any `args` to the constructor. Here is a modified version of your `Button_On_Click()` method that uses this approach:

```
def Button_On_Click(self):
    # myDdi = MDDropDownItem(
    #     # size_hint_x = None,
    #     # width = dp(100),
    #     # pos_hint = {"right": 1, "center_y": 0.5},
    #     text='SELECT POSITION')
    myDdi = MDDropDownItem()
    myDdi.text = 'SELECT POSITION'
```

Another issue is your statement:

```
myDdi.on_release = myMenu.open()
```

That statement is executing `myMenu.open()` and assigning its return value to `myDdi.on_release`. If you are trying to assign a method to `myDdi.on_release`, you must assign the method, not its return value. Just replace that line with:

```
myDdi.on_release = myMenu.open
```

Note the lack of `()`.